# Is there a PHP equivalent to the '||' double pipe assignment operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I apologize if this has been answered before, but it always seems hard to run a successful Google search on special characters or non-letter code. I have searched, but can't seem to find anything that has addressed this before.

But is there a PHP equivalent to the `||` assignment that exists in Javascript. Note: I don't just mean an `or` comparison operator. I'm looking to assign a value to the first item that returns non-false (maybe that's an underlying difference between the two languages that might prevent this from being possible?)

I know I could do

```
$x = null
$y = "value"
$val = x ? x : y    //$val now equals "value"
```

But I just saw the elegant way in which Javascript does it

```
$val = x || y
```

If it isn't possible, is the Ternary Operator in PHP the standard for going about this?

**Edit**

As I suspected, the question has been asked before. But after finding the specific terms for those operations in Javascript and PHP, I hope it might help in terms of accessibility through searching for this topic.

> **[var1] = x || y** Doesn't really seem to have its own term(?)

and

> **[var1] ||= x** seems to be referred to as "Double Pipe Equals"

and in PHP

> **[var1] = x ?: y** seems to be "Shorthand Ternary" (and also the solution to my question)

Comment: Did you try it with PHP?

Comment: @JohnConde [It doesn't work](http://3v4l.org/vuWaU) (or did I miss something?)

Comment: II operator is a valid operator in PHP

Comment: Does `||` do what you describe in JavaScript ("assign a value to the first item that returns non-false")? I thought it would be a simple Boolean OR there too.

Comment: @JohnConde — An `||` expression in PHP evaluates as nothing or `1`.

Comment: @kingkero You didn't miss anything. But this is easily testable and the OP should have simply tried it instead of asking here.

Comment: @halfer — In JavaScript, `||` evaluates as the left hand side if the LHS is true, otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side.

Comment: @JohnConde — It is easy enough to test that the specific `||` syntax doesn't work in the same way in PHP as it does in JS, but that isn't what the question is asking. It's asking there is an equivalent in PHP.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks - learn something new every day!

Comment: @JohnConde so then the OP is asking if there's an equivalent

Comment: You could use the shorthand ternary statement `?:` as in `$val = $x ?: $y;`

Comment: As I thought, this question has been asked before. My apologies. However, it was done so in fairly specific terms so that it's relatively difficult to find through a search. Is there a universal term for that type of assignment in Javascript `(x = y || z)`? I think if I were able to rephrase the question title in those sort of terms, it would be more accessible to get to the answer.